# why data value is 0

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

i want to apply formula. but getting 0 at output.

```
#include "HX711.h"
int data;
HX711 scale(A1, A0);		// parameter "gain" is ommited; the default value 128 is used by the library

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);

  scale.set_scale(2280.f);                 
  scale.tare();				      

}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("one reading:\t");
  data==(scale.get_units()/10);
  Serial.println(data);


		        // put the ADC in sleep mode
  delay(500);

}
```

Comment: why do you have == in `data==(scale.get_units()/10);`?

Answer (score 2):

It's zero because you never assign it a value.

Here you are comparing the current value of `data` (0) with the results of your calculation:

```
data==(scale.get_units()/10);
```

I think you intended to use the assignment, not comparison, operator `=`:

```
data = (scale.get_units()/10);
```